# Grails autocompile not in development environment

Tags: grails, auto-compile

I am running Grails 2.1 in a environment called "local" because "development" is reserved for a staging system. But I want to have to auto compile like in dev mode, i.e. if I am changing a controller the changes are compiled at one without rerunning "run-app". The parameter grails.gsp.enable.reload=true doesn't work.

Any hints are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Reto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try starting up with

```
grails local -reloading run-app
```

Comment: Thanks indeed, that did the job. You just need to set environment to local to this syntax:

grails -Dgrails.env=local -reloading run-app