# Grails autocompile broken after upgrade from 2.1 to 2.2.4

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, auto-compile

I hope you might can help me.

I recently upgraded our grails project from version 2.1 to 2.2.4 and now the autocompile/reload is broken => Everytime a make changes in Controller/Services/Taglibs I have to restart the app to see them.

Console attributes like in this thread [Grails autocompile not in development environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807207/grails-autocompile-not-in-development-environment) don't work for me. I also did some research on google but I couldn't find anything which helped.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:
Thanks for your help so far, I could solve the problem. I have updated the system class path to the path of the new grails version, now it works :-). It's somehow strange as the sdk was set correctly in Intellij Idea.

Comment: Are you using IDE like IntelliJidea or  command line for running "grails run-app" ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882589/grails-2-3-0-auto-reloading-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJIdea try using: (Tested on IntelliJIDea 11 and 12 with grails 2.2.2)

**EDIT**: Jar version case also included for different grails versions.

```
grails -Dserver.port=8096 -javaagent:${GRAILS_HOME}/lib/org.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.1.x.jar -Xverify:none run-app
```

NOTE: where 1.1.x is the version of jar in case of grails 2.2.2 it is 1.1.1 and in case of 2.2.4 it is 1.1.3

But, if you are using command line try using

`grails -reloading run-app` without any "-D" system property reloading should work fine. (Not tested though) Reference: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8951?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Comment: 1.1.3 is in case of 2.2.4, not 2.4.0

Comment: Right :P, Correcting my answer now...Thanks Anyways...:)